# How to change numpy array from (128,128,3) to (3,128,128)?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm reading in an image which is (128,128,3), but I have a processing function that accepts numpy array (3,128,128). I tried using `.reshape(3,128,128)` but the image was changed from the original. Is there a way I can change the shape of the numpy array without changing the image?

```
img = cv2.imread("elephant copy.jpg") #(128,128,3)
```

This is the function I want to pass the image to:

```
def deprocess_image(x):
    x = np.subtract(x, x.mean(), out=x, casting="unsafe")
    x = np.divide(x, x.std()+1e-5, out=x, casting="unsafe")
    x = np.multiply(x, 0.1, out=x, casting="unsafe")

    x = np.add(x, 0.5, out=x, casting="unsafe")
    x = np.clip(x, 0, 1)

    x = np.multiply(x, 255, out=x, casting="unsafe")
    x = x.transpose((1, 2, 0))
    x = np.clip(x, 0, 255).astype('uint8')
    return x
```

The function converts gradient descent into an image and it should return something like this: [image]

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean the image has changed?

Comment: I think the image has changed because when I passed it through the function (I just added it to the question), it returns a completely black image when it should be returning something else.

Comment: Does the function return a variable or save an image?, With what function do you show the image?

Comment: It returns an numpy array, which I then save using scipy.misc.imsave

Comment: doesn't look like anything in deprocess() depends on indexing , so the math and input values are responsible for *it returns a completely black image* , not the indexing

Answer (score 4):

You can use [numpy.swapaxes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html) to change the order like so:

```
a = np.random.rand(128,128,3)
print(a.shape)  # (128, 128, 3)

b = np.swapaxes(a, 2,0)
print(b.shape)  # (3, 128, 128)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using `transpose`

You describe the shape as `(128, 128, 3)` and you want `(3, 128, 128)`
This can happen one of two ways
Consider the array `a`

```
a = np.random.rand(128, 128, 3)
```

***case 1***

```
# swap these two
#   ________
#  /        \
# (128, 128, 3)

a.transpose(2, 1, 0)
#           ^     ^
#           |     |
# make the last    \ make the first
# dimension the      dimension the
# first dimension    last dimension
```

***case 2***

```
# 3 goes to first spot
#   ________
#  /        \
# (128, 128, 3)
#  \____/ \__/
# each 128 shifts

#                 2nd dimension
#                 now last
a.transpose(2, 0, 1)
#           ^  ^
#           |   \
# make the last  \  make the first
# dimension the     dimension the
# first dimension   second dimension
```